# Data binding with ASP.Net MVC and Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm new to working with ASP.Net MVC and Kendo controls.

I have looked at this demo page: [Kendo Grid Binding to local data](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/local-data-binding)

and it seems that it shouldn't be hard at all, and yet I don't know what I'm missing.

I get the data from a function that retrieves it from a SQL database in SurveyDataManager.cs.

```
public static List<SurveySummary> GetSurveySummary(int resourceTag)
    {
        List<SurveySummary> surveySummaryList = new List<SurveySummary>();

        try
        {
            using (ESSDataContext ess_context = new ESSDataContext())
            {
                var surveySummaryRec = ess_context.fn_ESS_SurveySummary(resourceTag).ToList();

                foreach (var item in surveySummaryRec)
                {
                    SurveySummary surveySummary = new SurveySummary()
                    {
                        SurveyID = item.SurveyHeaderID,
                        SurveyName = item.SurveyName,
                        SurveyInstructions = item.SurveyInstructions,
                        SurveyDescription = item.SurveyDescription,
                        Mandatory = item.Mandatory,
                        DueDate = item.DueDate,
                        Status = item.Status

                    };
                    surveySummaryList.Add(surveySummary);
                }                    
               
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("Getting the survey summary failed for user with resource tag: " + resourceTag);
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
        }

        return surveySummaryList;

    }
```

This is called by the Controller (HomeController's Index):

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var surveySummary = SurveyDataManager.GetSurveySummary(User.GetResourceTag());
        return PartialView("~/Areas/Survey/Views/MySurveys.cshtml", surveySummary);         
    }
```

Here is the code in my MySurveys.cshtml file:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc
@using Entities.Survey


@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SurveySummary>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.SurveyName).Title("Survey Name").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.SurveyDescription).Title("Description").Width(150);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Originator).Title("Originator").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.DueDate).Title("Due Date").Width(125);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Status).Title("Status").Width(140);
            })
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
            .Scrollable()
            .Groupable()
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .Refresh(true)
                .PageSizes(true)
                .ButtonCount(5))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                //.Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Home"))
                .PageSize(20)
            )
)
```

I get an empty grid, with the correct column names (titles), but no content. The SurveySummaryList definitely has at least one item in it, but it is not shown in the grid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: Hint: `.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()` - but you aren't using AJAX. You need to pass-in your Partial View's own ViewModel or ViewData.

Comment: Yes, I used the debugger, that's how I made sure there is a record in the list. I don't know how to pass in the Partial View's own ViewModel or ViewData. If you know of a link to a good tutorial that shows what I should do, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realised I was sending a list back, so I needed to change the cshtml file to:

```
@model IEnumerable<Symplexity.ESS.Entities.Survey.SurveySummary>


@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
...
```

Instead of what I had done previously as can be seen in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SurveySummary>(Model)` instead of `@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SurveySummary>()`?

Comment: I get the error, "cannot convert from Entities.Survey.SurveySummary' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Entities.Survey.SurveySummary>' " if I follow this.